# Error uninitialized constant with a class inheritance

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance

Clearly there is something off with how I understand it in ruby.  I have 3 ruby files main, base, and derived.  I have two classes `Derived` specializes from `Base`.

/bin/main.rb

```
require './lib/base'
```

/lib/base.rb

```
require './lib/derived'
class Base

end
```

/lib/derived.rb

```
require './lib/base'
class Derived < Base

end
```

running with rake `ruby './bin/main.rb'`

```
 `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Base (NameError)
```

What is causing the error?

Edit:
   I just realized one point I was missing was that I forgot that `require` is a Kernel#method, that I do not need to keep on top of my code every time like I normally do with other languages.

Comment: You are requiring `base` from `derived` and `derived` from `base`. That's an infinite loop.

Comment: @Petr, I knew somehow the mistake was something along those lines, thank you for confirming it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue here is that the require `'./lib/derived'` in the `/lib/base.rb` file is actually causing `/lib/derived.rb` to be parsed before `Base` is declared in `/lib/base.rb`.  Try this, instead:

/bin/main.rb

```
require './lib/base'
require './lib/derived'

puts 'Success!'
```

/lib/base.rb

```
class Base

end
```

/lib/derived.rb

```
require './lib/base'
class Derived < Base

end
```

This allows the declarations to occur in the proper order.

As a side note, it isn't technically necessary to `require './lib/base'` in `lib/main.rb`, since it's actually successfully included in `lib/derived.rb`, but it is good form if `Base` is used directly in the body of `lib/main.rb`.

Comment: Thanks, now it makes sense, though I was hoping to require the subclasses  only in the base class to make it act like a factory, hiding the sub class details from the client (main.rb).

Comment: You can do that in a couple of different ways.  First, you could use a loader file to require all of your project's dependencies, which is how most frameworks do it.  In this simple example, you could reasonably just skip the `'lib/derived.rb'` file altogether and declare both the `Base` and `Derived` classes in `'lib/base.rb'`, more like a library may do it.  If you have to have separate source files, just require `'lib/derived.rb'` from the bottom of `'lib/base.rb'` anywhere after you've completed the declaration of `Base`.